# Joint continuous random variables pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following problem that I think I know how to solve, but I don't see why the given choices are as they are:

```
Suppose X and Y are jointly continuous random variables with joint 
probability density function given by

f(x, y) = 1/c, x > 0, y > 0, x^2 + y^2 ≤ 2; or 0 otherwise

where c is a normalising constant which does not depend on x and y.

What's the value of c?
```

What's the upper limit of the integrals? We integrate from 0 to what? 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrate over the part of the circle with radius $\sqrt{2}$ that lies in the first quadrant.  If you *really* want to integrate, $y$ can travel from $0$ to $\sqrt{2-x^2}$, and then $x$ can travel from $0$ to $\sqrt{2}$.  Or else we can change to polar coordinates.

There is no need to integrate, since the area is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: So c is essentially the area?

Comment: @SorinCioban: I would say **exactly** the area.  In general, if you have a density function which is a constant $k$ over a two-dimensional region of (non-zero) area $A$, then $k=\frac{1}{A}$.  Since in your case the constant is being called $\frac{1}{c}$, we have $c=A$.